# What should a 10k user do with a rollback war flag?

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, rollbacks

I have just had an auto rollback war flag come through the 10k queue. However, as theres no "real" rollback war flag I'm basically left going "well thats nice" and moving on. As far as I can see all I could do is:

- Roll it back to my prefered version - further enflaming the roll back war
- Ignore it
- Flag as invalid if its invalid

What should a 10k user do on seeing a rollback war flag (assuming the flag is valid)?

> [image]

Comment: I almost asked a question on why the rollback war is triggered when the user engages in a rollback war with himself, so it's funnny how these same uncommon flags make people wonder different things

Comment: @psubsee2003 Also a very fair question, and pretty much the only time such a flag is going to be invalid

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's not really with himself, it started by the OP rolling back an edit by other user then, when he probably understood it was good edit after all, he rolled back his rollback. If someone keeps rolling back his own revisions I don't think it will raise a flag. (worth checking though!)

Comment: @ShadowWizard based on [What triggers the “possible rollback war” flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121948/what-triggers-the-possible-rollback-war-flag?rq=1), it only takes 2 rollbacks by the same person to trigger the flag.  Of course, it wasn't answered by a dev, so there could be more checking of timestamps and other situtions, but on the surface it seems like his 2nd rollback is what triggered it (and why I said it was with himself since the trigger was a rollback of his own post).

Comment: As for the question here, I think such flags should not appear in the 10K queue, the correct way to handle real rollback war is to put temporary lock on the post to prevent further edits, and maybe send warning to the offending sides. Neither of these can be done by non-moderators.

Comment: @RichardTingle actually, reading the post I linked, it seems to be a dup, as he is asking the same question, and Robert's answer pretty much answers it... trusted users shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: If you think something wrong is going on and you cannot resolve the situation - just call the moderator.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It does seem to be answered within the comments on that one. "Nothing" does seem to suggest we shouldn't see these at all though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You can help out the moderators if the situation is innocuous. But it is hard to judge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the feature for 10k+ users to handle flags has been discontinued a long time ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put an end to rollback wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/put-an-end-to-rollback-wars)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at it and see that it is indeed a problem, or determine that it's not, it's actually helpful for us if you provide an "other" flag that describes what you saw. Adding a second flag to either validate or dispute the original helps sort it higher on our list and lets us at a glance see how we should act on this.

In fact, an "other" flag left [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219876/the-possible-rollback-war-flag-isnt-being-triggered-by-community-wiki-posts) was the only thing that remained and was what finally clued us in that something needed to be done on that question.

It might not be the most helpful to expose this to 10k users, but you can at least help warn us about real problems that are developing in a question (or identify false positives).

Comment: Ok, so obvious rollback war --> ignore, non obvious problem --> other, invalid --> invalid. Or should obvious rollback wars get an "other" too?

Comment: @RichardTingle - Yes, I'd recommend an "other" flag for something you see as an obvious rollback war, because all we see in the moderator tools is the last revision. An "other" flag saying "yes, this is a problem you should look into", moves it up our list and tells us we should act on this now. Flags in both cases are helpful.